# Escribir números y después de cierta cantidad pueda ingresar un punto y dos números más con Jquey

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una función donde el usuario escriba números (Hasta ahí todo bien), Pero después de escribir digamos 10 números pudiera escribir un punto y dos números más, ejemplo (8954563108.39) y ya no lo deje ingresar más números como lograría hacerlo?

Código Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#txtxNumero').keypress(function(tecla) {
        if(tecla.charCode < 48 || tecla.charCode > 57) return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero te sirva.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#txtxNumero').keypress(function(tecla) {
                    if(tecla.charCode < 48 || tecla.charCode > 57){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                       if(jQuery(this).val().toString().length <= 12){
                           if(jQuery(this).val().toString().length == 10)
                               jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val() + ".");
                       }else{
                           return false;
                       }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Gracias, si sirvió!!!!

Comment: Tengo un inconveniente y es que al momento de uno copiar un texto y este tiene letras lo deja pegar normal, y no debería dejarlo, Lo que sí debería es que si yo tengo quiero copiar ejemplo 895456310839 entonces al momento de pegar me debería aparecer 8954563108.39 (Con el punto después de los 10 números), como lograría hacer esto?

Answer (score 2):

acomode un poco la función que uso para validar decimales, quizás no es lo más fácil de leer del mundo pero cumple su cometido.

Podes ingresar hasta 10 números previos al punto , y sólo 2 después.

```js
$('body').on('keypress', '.decimal' ,function (e) {
 
 if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which != 44 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
     e.preventDefault();
 }
 if( $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf('.') , $(this).val().length).length > 2) 
           e.preventDefault();

 if( $(this).val().length > 9 && $(this).val().indexOf('.')==-1)
 {
   if(event.which != 46) e.preventDefault();
 }

 if (event.which == 46 || event.which == 44) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (($(this).val().replace(/[^.]/g, "").length) == 0)
       $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="text" class="decimal">
</body>
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, también me sirvió!!!

Comment: Tengo un inconveniente y es que al momento de uno copiar un texto y este tiene letras lo deja pegar normal, y no debería dejarlo, Lo que sí debería es que si yo tengo quiero copiar ejemplo 895456310839 entonces al momento de pegar me debería aparecer 8954563108.39 (Con el punto después de los 10 números), como lograría hacer esto?

Comment: @JairoArturoCifuentes, teniendo en cuenta que lo que preguntas, es otro tema, te recomiendo que crees una nueva pregunta!

Comment: Vale, creí que era redundante volver hacer una pregunta similar. :D